# Decrease font size when it reach last point of div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends I want to decrease `font size` when parent `div` reaches `100px height` following is my code or u can see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/VzBw9/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="divContent"  contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off">
    Start Typing</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.divContent').keyup(function(){
        //alert($(this).height())
        if (($(this).height()) > 100)
        {   
        var font = $('.divContent').css('font-size');
        alert(font)
        $(this).css('font-size',''+font-2+'px')
        alert(font);
            }
        })
```

Please help friends ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close with this. Take a look at the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VzBw9/3/. You have to cast your font variable to number, as you were trying to subtract 2 from "16px" which clearly isn't a number:

```
$('.divContent').keyup(function(){
    //alert($(this).height())
    if (($(this).height()) > 100){  
        var font = $('.divContent').css('font-size');
        alert(font);
        font = parseInt(font) - 2;
        font += 'px';

        $(this).css('font-size',font);
        alert(font);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the "-" on the String "16px". Just cast before

```
$('.divContent').keyup(function(){
    //alert($(this).height())
    if (($(this).height()) > 100)
    {   
    var font = $('.divContent').css('font-size');
    var fontSizeAsNumber = font.substring(0,2);
    var newFontSize = fontSizeAsNumber -2;
    $(this).css('font-size',newFontSize+'px');
        }
    })
```